# Dagger2 не создает DaggerComponent

Tags: kotlin, dagger2

возникла проблема при использовании Dagger2, не генерится класс DaggerAppComponent, после билда приложения[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какая версия dagger?

Comment: код в виде кода включите в вопрос

Comment: версия dagger 2.35.1